# Implementing javascript confirm box in code behind C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to implement javascript confirm box from code behind.

My requirement is in a method I need to raise a confirm box ,based on the result I need to implement diff functionalites

For Example;

if OK of Confirm Box the add Tax

if cancel Then do not add tax

I am trying something like this but its not helping me

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "confirm", "confirm('Add tax');", true);
```

Can anyone help.

my sample Code is

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Double mrp = 200.00;

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "confirm", "return confirm('Add Tax');", true);
    if (Confirm == "Ok")
    {
        //Add tax to mrp
    }
    else
    {
        //No tax for mrp
    }
}
```

Thank You..

Comment: You can get the value form confirm box if you write like this. Means you won't get weather user has pressed ok or cancle.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail. Means where are the button inside grid or somewhere else?

Comment: its outside a grid @Shekhar ...

Comment: You need to explain it a bit more about structure and what exactly do you want?

Comment: @Shekhar I want to get the value of confirm box from code behind ...

Comment: There is no way of **directly getting the value of confirm in C#**

Comment: @Shekhar ok...Is there any other way to implement my functionality...

Comment: Where do you want the value On button click? It would be better if you can explain a bit more.

Comment: still not enough information. Please put your `html` and your control whose value you want to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you try like this.:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function Confirm() {
            var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
            confirm_value.type = "hidden";
            confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
            if (confirm("Do you want to save data?")) {
                confirm_value.value = "Yes";
            } else {
                confirm_value.value = "No";
            }
            document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:Button ID="btnConfirm" runat="server"
                  OnClientClick = "Confirm()"
                  OnClick="OnConfirm" 
                  Text="Raise Confirm"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Fetching the User input server side

Now server side we need to fetch the user input that we stored in the dynamic hidden field and then based on whether he has selected OK or Cancel we need to execute different code.

```
public void OnConfirm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
    if (confirmValue == "Yes")
    {
        //Your logic for OK button
    }
    else
    {
        //Your logic for cancel button
    }
}
```

**From [Server Side (Code Behind) Yes No Confirmation Message Box in ASP.Net](http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Server-Side-Code-Behind-Yes-No-Confirmation-Message-Box-in-ASPNet.aspx)**

Comment: Yes currently I am implementing it the way you have suggested.So, is this the best way that we can do to implement this functionality???

Comment: I think So.. As per your requirement I think this is the best way to do this. And Don't forget to mark it as answer it it helped you. Thnak you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ScrptManager`  like:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "confirm", "return confirm('Your massage to be Displayed.');", true);
```

You can refer this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/414111/confirmation-message-in-asp-net) for more details.

Or you can try like this.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Message", "if(confirm('Sorry, but there is already a Primary Stakeholder assigned to this ticket. Would you like to replace the existing data?')){alert('OK');}else{alert('cancel');}",true);
```

In the adove code If user press `OK` button, It will display alert box with message **OK** else it will display alert box with message **Cancel**.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "__Mensagem", "if (confirm('" + CustomMessage+ "')){$(\"#" + btnSave.ClientID + "\").click();}", true);
```

Can you try this. In this if confirm returns true then it returns the click event of the button.

Comment: can you tel me how could i get the value of confirm box, i.e., whether ok or cancel

Comment: Check the link I have put in the answer.

Comment: @RahulGokani it is not going to help him because he will bot be able to know which button of confirm is being pressed.

Comment: @Shekhar Confirm returns only true or false. In the second code it shows that if it is true then it will execute the true statement or it will go into the else statement. It is not that which button is pressed.

Comment: your are right but how he will get value in C#? Because on that he will like to do code?

Comment: Check the edit which I made. In that he can simply put `$(\"#" + txtBox.ClientID + "\").Text` to access the values of element like this..

Comment: @RahulGokani my requirement is exactly what Shekhar had said..so,please tell me something very similar to that..thnx

Comment: @Cherry did you try the above comment or the last edit which I made.?

Comment: What I am telling you in my last answer that when user click `OK` it will return the click event of the `btnSave` then put your logic in side the `btnSave.Click` event.

Comment: @RahulGokani can u suggest a solution for my edited post..Thnx

Comment: thnx but how to redirect user to page after confirmation pls

Answer (score 0):

**please try following:**

```
Double mrp = 200.00;
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sb.Append("var x=''; var r=confirm('Press a button!');");
sb.Append("if (r==true){alert('ok'); x='" + mrp + "';}");
sb.Append("else{ alert('cancel');}");
sb.Append("document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=x;");
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "confirm", sb.ToString(), true);
```

aspx page:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Actually my requirement is to do it from source behind..Currently I am implementing it like this only..but i am trying to find a solution where every thing is in source behind

Comment: @Cherry: I changed my answer. you can write you javascript code right in the page.