# Accepting return value of Javascript Confirm box in C#

Tags: c#, javascript

I have to get the value from the javascript Confirm Popupbox in my codebehind in c#
Here is my code. I am able to display the popup box using this

```
if (data.certFileName != CommonVariables.certfile || data.dataFileName != CommonVariables.datafile)
{
    string msg = "You have changed Arrival Filenames. Press OK To regenerate Autosys File. Press Cancel to Update the existing Autosys file";
    string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">confirm('" + msg + "');</script>";
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "ConfirmMsg", script);
}
```

How do i accept the value?

Please help.

Comment: 1. Do you want to post that response back via AJAX, or as part of a form?
2. Are you using WebAPI?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing javascript confirm box in code behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674874/implementing-javascript-confirm-box-in-code-behind)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (data.certFileName != CommonVariables.certfile || data.dataFileName != CommonVariables.datafile)
{
    string msg = "You have changed Arrival Filenames. Press OK To regenerate Autosys File. Press Cancel to Update the existing Autosys file";
    string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">return confirm('" + msg + "');</script>";
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "ConfirmMsg", script);
}
```

you forgot to write return

Comment: But where will i get the retun value?

Comment: i have wrote the code u replace ur code with code in my answer try it

Comment: @user2124167 you can do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674874/implementing-javascript-confirm-box-in-code-behind)

Comment: @Chirag: I get the popup box, which I was geeting earlier. Now i want to capture whether user pressed OK or Cancel. How can i get that?

Comment: wait i will try and give u answer