# how to ask OK/Cancel with ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript() in VB ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can I easily popup a message and get back OK or Cancel, with one line of .vb ASP.NET code as easily as this pops up an OK box?

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "AlertScript", "alert('" & message & "');", True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way is using `confirm()` function:

```
' using single if
Me.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "ConfirmScript", "if(confirm('" & message & "')) { // do something }", True)

' using if-else
Me.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "ConfirmScript", "if(confirm('" & message & "')) { // do something } else { // do other thing }", True)
```

Or calling a function which containing `confirm()`:

**JS**

```
<script>
    function showConfirm(msg) {
        if (confirm(msg)) {
            // do something
        } else {
            // do other thing
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Code behind**

```
Me.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "ConfirmScript", "showConfirm('" & message & "')", True)
```

If you want to receive returned value (`OK`/`Cancel`) in server-side, you can store return value in a hidden field, handle `OnClick` event from the control which displays confirm box and use `Request.Form` as provided in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674874/implementing-javascript-confirm-box-in-code-behind-c-sharp).